# Jmeter-Passing parameter in csv

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When i passed parameters(username and password)in csv.Jmeter fetching the csv parameters wrong that is,i have passed 9876-54326,9876-54326 as username and password in csv but when i ran the test,the response that came is

login=%229876-54326%22&password=%229876-54326%22
this is shown in view result tree listener.

So it is accepting %229876-54326%22 instead of 9876-54326 and same for password
Waiting for the feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ensure No Speace/Speacial chars in cell data for User Name and Password as It is taking %22 for space/Speacial chars.

Comment: Still not accepted,and there is no special character and also if email and password are the credentials,then special character will come in form of @. that is abc@asd.com.It is coming same in encrypted form.Please give me the solution

Answer (score 0):

Actually %22 is a code for " character. Make sure you don't use that character in you Jmeter request. Just use ${name_of_parameter_in_csv_file} variable in requests.

Comment: Am using name=login and its value ={login}

Comment: Am using  name=login,and its value =${login} and name =password ,and and its value= ${password} respectively and credentials in csv are 9876-54326,9876-54326 as login and password.

Comment: Now,it is accepted but getting "Please enter valid username and password" in response and the credentials,url's are correct.Please suggest

Comment: Add **View response tree** listener to your test plan and check the **Request** tab in the failed request.

Comment: That has already been done. In request tab
login=%222020-00001%22&password=%222020-00001%22" this m getting,i dont know from where %22 is coming in credentials.